# How to add values from one array to another?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays, from which one has to complete the other:

```
struct Score {
    let name: String
    let isComplete: Bool
    let finalScore: Int
}

var scores = [
    Score(name: "Steven", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Helen", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Adalbert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Christian", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Susan", isComplete: false, finalScore: 3),
    Score(name: "Julia", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Robert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Mercedes", isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
    Score(name: "Gwendolin", isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
]



struct Complete {
    let name: String
    let isComplete: Bool
}

var complete = [
    Complete(name: "Steven", isComplete: true),
    Complete(name: "Helen", isComplete: true),
    Complete(name: "Mercedes", isComplete: false),
    Complete(name: "Gwendolin", isComplete: true),
    // Name doesn´t exist in `score` and shouldn´t show up in the result:
    Complete(name: "nonexistingName", isComplete: true)
]
```

How could I complete the first array with the values from the second in a way that the result looks like this:

```
let result = [
    Score(name: "Steven", isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Helen", isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Adalbert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Christian", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Susan", isComplete: false, finalScore: 3),
    Score(name: "Julia", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Robert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Mercedes", isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
    Score(name: "Gwendolin", isComplete: true, finalScore: 2),
]
```

Usually I would post a draft of my try, but since I´m quite new to swift, I have to admit I have no idea. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A *dictionary* (mapping the name to the result) would be a better suited type for the scores. It allows to find and update entries efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately you should probably re-think your models, possibly with some sort of "Player" model so you don't have this kind of disconnect.

FWIW here's a safer/simpler way to do this with a dictionary:

```
struct Score {
    let name: String
    var isComplete: Bool
    let finalScore: Int
}

struct Complete {
    let name: String
    let isComplete: Bool
}

var scoresDictionary: [String : Score] = [:]

// this populates scoresDictionary with your array, keyed with the names
[   Score(name: "Steven", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Helen", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Adalbert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Christian", isComplete: false, finalScore: 12),
    Score(name: "Susan", isComplete: false, finalScore: 3),
    Score(name: "Julia", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Robert", isComplete: false, finalScore: 13),
    Score(name: "Mercedes", isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
    Score(name: "Gwendolin", isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
    ].forEach { scoresDictionary[$0.name] = $0}

let complete = [
    Complete(name: "Steven", isComplete: true),
    Complete(name: "Helen", isComplete: true),
    Complete(name: "Mercedes", isComplete: false),
    Complete(name: "Gwendolin", isComplete: true),
    // Name doesn´t exist in `score` and shouldn´t show up in the result:
    Complete(name: "nonexistingName", isComplete: true)
]

//Updates only the found values in scoresDictionary
complete.forEach { scoresDictionary[$0.name]?.isComplete = $0.isComplete }

// The dictionary is updated, but in case you just want the Scores, this gives you an array
let result: [Score] = Array(scoresDictionary.values)
```

Comment: `let result: [Score] = Array(scoresDictionary.values)` is getting the Score values from the dictionary and putting them in an array

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tried with a very big Array. It´s working absolutely fine.

Comment: @  PEEJWEEJ: Yeah, I just oversaw it in the hurry.

Comment: @ PEEJWEEJ: Would it be even better to setup the [Complete] as Dictionary as well? Like [String: Bool]?

Comment: Keep in mind these assume unique names. If that's a problem I would suggest switching to more of a database model with UIDs

Comment: @JoschHazard If that's an option, maybe. Not knowing how any of this is used makes it hard to make any sort of recommendation

Comment: [Complete] has to be updated quite often. Of course, I could add new values with complete.append... But if I want to change an existing value, problems are coming again. But maybe another time, now I´m very satisfied with your solution!

Comment: Any reason to not just use your existing `Score`s? it contains the same information.

Comment: You mean existing [Complete]? because `complete` has to be updatable as well. So if i want to add or change values in complete, it seems i have to take the same detour as in updating `score`. To be specific: Don´t know yet if it´s really possible, but I´m trying to set up an array or dictionary, somehow like `complete = Complete(name: String, isComplete: Bool)` out of checkboxes in a nstableview. This array or dictionary gets updated each time a checkbox is changed, after that it´s getting stored in UserDefaults and serves to filter the content in NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we just iterate `scores`, looking for a matching `Complete`. If we find one, we return a `Score` with the attribute `isComplete` set `true` or `false`. If we don't find one, we return the original `Score` unchanged.

```
var final: [Score] = scores.map { aScore in

    let comp = complete.first { aScore.name == $0.name }
    if let comp = comp {
        return Score(name: aScore.name, isComplete: comp.isComplete || aScore.isComplete, finalScore: aScore.finalScore)
    }
    return aScore
}

final.forEach {
    print($0.name, $0.isComplete, $0.finalScore)
}
```

Prints:

```
Steven true 12
Helen true 12
Adalbert false 12
Christian false 12
Susan false 3
Julia false 13
Robert false 13
Mercedes false 2
Gwendolin true 2
```

Comment: "filter + first" can be simplified using `first(where:)`

Comment: I just tried it out and it´s just awesome! Need a little time to exactly understand how it works. Thank you very much! One more question: Is this method iterating `scores` for every single `complete` value? So in this case 5 times? Because my Score array is quite big.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, updated! @Josch Hazard, no, it iterates `scores` once, potentially iterating the whole `complete` array for each value in `scores`. So if `scores` is large, and `complete` relatively short, this should be a pretty fast solution.

Comment: It searches `complete` for it's match with every item from `scores`. This works, but is very inefficient.

Comment: It would actually be more efficient if the iterations were swapped

Comment: You're right @PEEJWEEJ, this is not the most efficient solution. +1 to yours.